# ActiveRecord find all records with certain count on has_many relation's status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, one-to-many

I have a `Post` model and a `Comment` model. A `Post` `has_many` `Comment`s. Every `Comment` has a `status` attribute, which is technically an integer column at the database (Postgres) level, but is listed as an enum at the ActiveRecord model declaration level: `enum status: [:draft, :published, :removed]`. I want to construct an ActiveRecord query to find:

All the Post models with either:

1. 0 related comment models
2. comment models all of whose statuses are published

I think I've found a way to satisfy the first constraint:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {id: nil})
```

The second constraint has been giving me trouble, though. I can find all the Posts that have *at least* one comment with a published status, but not *only and all* comments with the published status:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {status: :published})
```

I need a way to get the second constraint working properly and to combine the two searches (if possible).

I hope I don't need to use plain sql to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to flip the query to avoid dropping down into SQL. Instead of searching for Posts where all Comments are published, search for Posts where none of the Comments are draft or removed:

```
Post.where('id NOT IN (?)', Post.select(:id).includes(:comments).where(comments: {status: [:draft, :removed]}))
```

EDIT FROM OP:

SO didn't allow me enough characters in a response to explain how I got from your query to one that worked. If this is the wrong way to do this, please feel free to correct me. I just wanted this stuff included for posterity...

First of all, thank you. The idea to flip the logic along with this example query with a subquery got me to a solution that worked. Here's how that went, in case anyone comes here in the future:

Your exact query returned this AR error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery has too many columns

So, I removed the `select(:id)` and added a `pluck(:id)` to the subquery to fix the error.

Then, for some reason, the `where('id NOT IN (?), [])` always empties the result array/relation, even when the array of ids to blacklist is empty, as shown in that example. So in the end, I wound up with this query which solves me problem:

```
Post.where.not(id: Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {status: [:draft, :removed]}).pluck(:id))
```

Comment: @pachun you can use .joins(:comments) instead of includes, since includes eager loads association to memory